# Android wrong action loads

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, android-manifest, intentfilter

I have an android application, I'm trying to put a splash screen in via a tutorial I found and I added an additional activity to the manifest "SplashScreen", however my other activity still loads first.  If I take the other one out, the splash screen will load but crashes.  How can I get the SplashScreen to load first?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="projectmp.android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MissionPlanner"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="projectmp.android.MissionPlanner" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Thanks

Comment: Remove the intent filter from your MissionPlanner declaration, it's not needed. Once you've done that and the SplashScreen crashes take a look at your LogCat output for the error.

Comment: I tried that earlier, it doesn't work, this is the error:

`[2011-07-10 07:17:32 - ProjectMP] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=projectmp.android/.MissionPlanner }
[2011-07-10 07:17:32 - ProjectMP] ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=projectmp.android/.MissionPlanner } from null (pid=-1, uid=-1) requires null
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you are launching it from still thinks that it is trying to launch `MissionPlanner`. It may be caching an earlier definition of your application. The default home screen launcher should not have this effect, but third-party ones, or home screen shortcuts, will.

Comment: I'm using eclipse, everything is default and I keep cleaning my project.  I tried multiple actions and categories under the intent filter.  Nothing works.

Comment: @Mike: The issue may be with your run configuration in Eclipse.